# Applying Primevue theme

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

Edit: As I was not able to figure this out, I instead dropped Vue3 and went back to Vue2 and switched to Vuetify.

I am completely new to Vue and decided to use Vue 3 for project, which is supposed to lead into my master thesis. As there are not very many UI libraries which are updated to run on Vue 3, I decided to go with Primevue.

Currently I am trying to apply one of Primevue's themes to my project, but the result is not very satisfying. I am using a dark theme, but the background is all white, while the components use the theme for the background and general styling.

[image: See the current application here]

I am hoping someone is able to help apply the styling correctly.

As a bonus question I am wondering whether it would be better to downgrade to Vue 2 and use a more well-established UI library such as Vuetify or BootstrapVue.

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import TieredMenu from 'primevue/tieredmenu';
import InputSwitch from 'primevue/inputswitch';

// import 'primevue/resources/themes/bootstrap4-light-blue/theme.css';
import 'primevue/resources/themes/bootstrap4-dark-blue/theme.css';
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
import 'primeflex/primeflex.css';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(VueApexCharts)
    .use(VueEllipseProgress)
    .component('TieredMenu', TieredMenu)
    .component('InputSwitch', InputSwitch)
    .mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="namegoeshere" >
    <router-view/>
    <div id="nav">
      <!--<router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style >
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue, having a look at the prime-vue documentation site with the devtools shows the following code is set on the body:

```
  body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: var(--surface-a);
      font-family: var(--font-family);
      font-weight: 400;
      color: var(--text-color);
   }
```

The variables used here come from the loaded theme. This solved the issue for me.

I couldn't find any direct information about having to set this in the docs.